# Is there any way to affect application sort in Disambiguation Dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, open-with, disambiguation

I'm testing "open with" dialog, witch also called as [Disambiguation Dialog](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending#disambiguation-dialog).

As shown in the following picture, I tried to put ComposeDemo App in the first place by setting [android:priority](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element), but it didn't work.

[Disambiguation Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr0fb.png)

Any other suggestions, or is it possible to do this? thanx in advance

Code is like this:

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".SecondActivity"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter
        android:priority="500"
        android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:scheme="content" />
        <data android:host="*" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Add code snippet.

Comment: Added. Looking forward to your reply